# The most efficient way to hide/show up to 100 DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Assume that you have at most 100 elements in which their types and format don't change but their context does. (They're basically rows)
These rows around bound to a input and going to change as the user types.

What would be the best approach for maximum performance? Reusing the elements, keeping all but changing their context? Anything else?

*Edit, Clarification:*
The search algorithm is unrelated but I do use MVVM (angularjs) framework so the search I'm doing is on JavaScript and is not a bottleneck; after getting the results, I update the accordingly.

Also I don't need to search for the elements over DOM, I do have  the references to elements, I want to minimize the run-time during the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the code, this will do,

```
$(element).css('display' , 'none');
```

But the performance issues depends on how you are finding those elements,
**The key is to wrap elements in to a container, and search for the elements within that container only**:

```
$('container').find('your_elements').css('display' , 'none');
```

**OR**

```
$('your_elements', 'container').css('display' , 'none');
```

Will do it.

**Never do:**

```
$('your_elements').css('display' , 'none');
```

JS will have to search entire dom for that

Answer (score 2):

If you have only 100 elements it doesn't really matter. Just set the `display` property of their style object to show or hide them.

Answer (score 0):

Use unique id of all rows and use jquery to manipulate it by changing their value..

Comment: ID should be unique in document using class instead is better approach.

Comment: @Kashif Naseem yes...using class is also effective solution but if there are twenty rows and you have to update 13th number row..then it will be difficult for any novice to select that row through class..so I adviced to use ID..as it is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Best way could be, wrap all those elements in a div and set style to the external div ( assuming they are together as you said they are rows )

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <!-- Your dom elements -->
</div>
```

Set proper style to your wrapper div.

And typically I dont think we need to worry about perf on such things as they are very trivial operations.

Comment: How could you add TR elements in DIV?

Comment: Actually, you need to worry about DOM manipulation performance as it is the worst performance bottleneck in most of the js applications.

Comment: I told that as the question said it had 100 elements only.

Answer (score 0):

I think create a CSS class with display none and apply that class to TR elements by doing this you will be able to utilize the jquery selector for later use.  `$('TR.hidden')`  and  `if(!$('TD').hasClass('hidden'))`